# Reading binary file in C++ and output result as hexdump

Tags: c++, fstream, binaryfiles, hexdump

I'm building a simpler version of `xxd` for a school project and I'm getting hung up on the file output when reading binary files only (i.e. when I read plain text files, everything works as expected).

Expected output:

```
0000000: 504b 0304 1400 0000 0800 70b6 4746 562d  PK........p.GFV-
0000010: e841 3600 0000 3f00 0000 0900 1c00 706c  .A6...?.......pl
0000020: 6169 6e2e 7478 7455 5409 0003 7307 d754  ain.txtUT...s..T
0000030: ba1d d754 7578 0b00 0104 f501 0000 0414  ...Tux..........
0000040: 0000 000b c9c8 2c56 00a2 e2fc dc54 85e2  ......,V.....T..
0000050: c4dc 829c 5485 92d4 8a12 ae10 a844 625e  ....T........Db^
0000060: 7e49 466a 9142 4e66 5eaa 4266 9e02 9003  ~IFj.BNf^.Bf....
0000070: 56a0 9096 9993 ca05 0050 4b01 021e 0314  V........PK.....
0000080: 0000 0008 0070 b647 4656 2de8 4136 0000  .....p.GFV-.A6..
0000090: 003f 0000 0009 0018 0000 0000 0001 0000  .?..............
00000a0: 00a4 8100 0000 0070 6c61 696e 2e74 7874  .......plain.txt
00000b0: 5554 0500 0373 07d7 5475 780b 0001 04f5  UT...s..Tux.....
00000c0: 0100 0004 1400 0000 504b 0506 0000 0000  ........PK......
00000d0: 0100 0100 4f00 0000 7900 0000 0000       ....O...y.....
```

Actual output:

```
0000000: 504b 0304 1400 0000 0800 70ffb6 4746 562d  PK........p.GFV-
0000010: ffe841 3600 0000 3f00 0000 0900 1c00 706c  .A6...?.......pl
0000020: 6169 6e2e 7478 7455 5409 0003 7307 ffd754  ain.txtUT...s..T
0000030: ffba1d ffd754 7578 0b00 0104 fff501 0000 0414  ...Tux..........
0000040: 0000 000b ffc9ffc8 2c56 00ffa2 ffe2fffc ffdc54 ff85ffe2  ......,V.....T..
0000050: ffc4ffdc ff82ff9c 54ff85 ff92ffd4 ff8a12 ffae10 ffa844 625e  ....T........Db^
0000060: 7e49 466a ff9142 4e66 5effaa 4266 ff9e02 ff9003  ~IFj.BNf^.Bf....
0000070: 56ffa0 ff90ff96 ff99ff93 ffca05 0050 4b01 021e 0314  V........PK.....
0000080: 0000 0008 0070 ffb647 4656 2dffe8 4136 0000  .....p.GFV-.A6..
0000090: 003f 0000 0009 0018 0000 0000 0001 0000  .?..............
00000a0: 00ffa4 ff8100 0000 0070 6c61 696e 2e74 7874  .......plain.txt
00000b0: 5554 0500 0373 07ffd7 5475 780b 0001 04fff5  UT...s..Tux.....
00000c0: 0100 0004 1400 0000 504b 0506 0000 0000  ........PK......
00000d0: 0100 0100 4f00 0000 7900 0000 0000 0000  ....O...y.......
```

[Here's a quick diff of the two files for easy reference.](https://www.diffchecker.com/e2m01e5i)

I have a feeling it's the way I'm reading the files. I decided to stick with the C++ libraries and use `std::ifstream` to read the files. Here's my implementation:

```
void DumpUtility::dump(const char* filename) {
    std::ifstream file(filename, std::ifstream::in|std::ifstream::binary); // open file for reading

    if(file.is_open()) { // ensure file is open and ready to go
        std::cout << std::hex << std::setfill('0'); // pad PC with leading zeros
        char buffer[this->bytesPerLine]; // buffer symbols

        while(file.good()) {
            file.read(buffer, this->bytesPerLine);
            std::cout << std::setw(7) << this->pc << ":";
            for(unsigned int i = 0; i < this->bytesPerLine; i++) {
                if(i % 2 == 0) std::cout << " ";

                std::cout << std::setw(2) << (unsigned short)buffer[i];
            }

            std::cout << "  ";
            for(unsigned int i = 0; i < this->bytesPerLine; i++) {
                if(isprint(buffer[i]) == 0) { // checks if character is printable
                    std::cout << ".";
                } else {
                    std::cout << buffer[i];
                }
            }
            std::cout << std::endl;
            this->pc += this->bytesPerLine;
        }
    } else {
        std::cerr << "Couldn't open file. General error..." << std::endl;
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    file.close();
}
```

So, `file.read(buffer, this->bytesPerLine);` is the line that reads the file and I format the data has hex via `iomanip`. I have also tried using `printf(%02X, (unsigned short)buffer[i]);` with no luck – same output.

#### What has been done

- Using multiple compilers to recompile program

  - `clang++ -O0 -g -Wall -c`
  - `g++ -g -Wall -c`
- Two versions of `g++`

  - 4.2.1 - OS X 10.10
  - 3.4.6 - Sun Solaris 10
- Debugging in `lldb` and `gdb` in order to see where exactly these extra F's come from, I found nothing.

It seems like `std::ifstream::read()` is doing something other than simply storing the special characters as they are. Does anyone know what these extra `F's` represent and can anyone point me in the right direction to resolve this?

**Note:** I'm trying to understand how to do this using `std::ifstream` as opposed to using `cstdio`. If worst comes to worst then I'll implement the method using the File IO utilities in `cstdio` instead. If I can't do this using `ifstream` then I'll gladly take the explanation so I can learn!

Comment: Your basic loop is incorrect; the file may be `good` when there is nothing more to read.  And what happens if the input file is not a multiple of `bytes_per_line`?  The loop should be `while ( file.read( buffer, bytes_per_line ) || file.gcount() > 0 )`; you also want to output `file.gcount()` bytes, rather than `bytes_per_line`.  (Actually, this is one case where the `while ( file.good() )` will work, _provided_ you use `file.gcount()` afterwards to get the number of bytes actually input.)

Comment: Also: `char buffer[this->bytesPerLine];` isn't legal C++; you need `std::vector<char> buffer( bytesPerLine );`.  (Or, make `bytesPerLine` a `static int const` member, initialized in the class definition.)

Comment: @JamesKanze the char pointer seems to be working without any warnings. Why exactly might this be wrong?

Comment: The dimensions of a C style array must be compile time constants.  If your code compiles, you're using an extension in one particular compiler.

Comment: Gotcha. I switched compilers to CC on Solaris and found that out the hard way. Thanks for the advice, I appreciate it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that your `char` type is signed. So when you write `(unsigned short)buffer[i]`, it is translated as char -> int -> unsigned short.

if the byte is under 0x7f, it is seen as >=0 and all is fine, but if not, it is internally padded with 1 bits to form a negative int. You first problem is on a `b6`. What actually happens is :

```
b6 (signed char) -> FFFFFFb6 (signed int) -> FFB6 (unsigned short)
```

Hopefully the fix is simple. You just have to write :

```
std::cout << std::setw(2) << (unsigned short) (unsigned char) buffer[i];
```

because now the conversion will correctly be :

```
b6 (signed char) -> b6 (unsigned char) -> b6 (signed int) -> b6 (unsigned short)
```

Comment: A couple of comments: first, there's no point in the `unsigned short`; just `unsigned` will do just as well.  Second, an alternative would be to use `unsigned char` for the buffer (or a buffer pointer), and just do the casting there.  (I prefer your solution, but both are valid.)  And finally, another alternative would be to use `buffer[i] & 0xFF`, and forgo the casting completely.

Comment: @JamesKanze, you're absolutely right! I was able to bitwise and by 0x7F and it accomplished the same thing!

Comment: @djthoms Anding 0x7F will change the value of some bytes.

Comment: @JamesKanze yes, I figured that out when I tested it.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
std::cout << std::setw(2) << (unsigned short)buffer[i] & 0xFF;
```

Or

```
std::cout << std::setw(2) << (unsigned short)(unsigned char)buffer[i];
```

Or

```
unsigned char buffer[this->bytesPerLine];
...
std::cout << (char)buffer[i];
```

Also `isprint` is used incorrectly with signed char. The issue is similar: when the char value is negative, it is expanded to negative integer, and not positive integer with value over 127 (what `isprint` expects).

So if you are using signed chars, the call shall be:

```
if(isprint((unsigned char)buffer[i]) == 0)
```

Comment: Why the cast in the first proposed solution?

Comment: @JamesKanze because type conversion goes through sign expansion.

Comment: But the `& 0xFF` pretty much eliminates any sign; it takes just the lower order 8 bits.

Comment: @JamesKanze it does. but conversion from `unsigned char` into any other (larger) ordinal type doesn't require `&` operation.

Comment: When there is no operation, you need the casts.  The whole point of using `& 0xFF` is that it doesn't require any explicit type conversions.  (It was the usual way of solving this problem back when there wasn't an `unsigned char` type.)